How should duplication between sites be addressed?
The question "Is BitCoin future-proof?" is a duplicate of the Stack Overflow question "Is bitcoin protocol future-proof?" with only a slightly different slant, and the same answer.  How should inter-site duplication like this be addressed?  Clearly, the question is on-topic here and probably would even have been asked here had this site existed at the time.  But it also seems odd to copy an answer from another location on SE (even if it is my own!).

Is this perhaps more suited for the main Meta.SO?  I'm not sure...

lol, I think you just asked a meta-meta-question.

Well luckily I think Meta.SO is also its own Meta.Meta.SO.  It's Meta all the way down :)

I've also been following the Economics SE proposal on A51, which I'm sure we'll end up redirecting some folks to once we're completed: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics

All bitcoin related question should be migrated from other Stack Exchange sites to Bitcoin.SE.
This means closing the questions on other sites (/flagging a moderator to do so), and editing it or commenting that a duplicate question exists here.

Right. BTW @Dori, how come you are a moderator? I kind of assumed I will be, given I proposed this on Area 51 :(

@Dori - http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7/how-were-the-initial-moderators-for-bitcoin-stack-exchange-chosen

I think just giving an answer with a link to the answer elsewhere until we are public and can migrate the questions is the best way to go at the moment.

While it's not 100% clear, I think the question was discussing what our procedure will be AFTER we go public. Obviously we can't redirect questions on StackOverflow et. al. here just yet :)
